# How can I create a CSS drawing that resizes fluidly?

Tags: css, fluid

How could I make my CSS drawings fluid, so that they would resize easily and could be used instead of an SVG image for a website and app? For instance, this [smiley face](https://codepen.io/gunderodd/pen/EqVgQX) drawing. Currently, the window cuts it off because it is set in absolute units. I've tried using relative units instead of pixels, but resizing just shifts all the elements of the image.

Is there a JS way of changing all units evenly to make three or four sizes of the drawing? Or a way to use variables to change every element while keeping them at the same ratios and spacing? [This](https://diana-adrianne.com/purecss-francine/) amazing painting seems to resize like I want mine to, but I can't tell what is making it responsive by looking over the code myself.

My example image:

```css
  #head {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  /*   border: px solid yellow; */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-70deg, #c9bb34 1%, #fceb51 65%, #fcfcd7);
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 10px;
}

#smile {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 10%, black);
  left: 150px;
  top: 250px;
  border-radius: 10% 70% 20% 30%;
}

#smile-cover {
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  width: 100px;
  height: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fceb51;
  top: 260px;
  left: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 60% 20% 10%;
}

#left-eye {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 10%, black);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 110px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 10px;
}

#right-eye {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 1%, black);
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;
}

#left-eye-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 23px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fceb51, #fcfcd7);
  top: 125px;
  left: 58px;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 25% 60%;
}

#right-eye-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fceb51, #fcfcd7);
  top: 125px;
  left: 320px;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 25% 70%;
}

#left-eye-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  height: 60px;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-70deg, #fceb51 1%, #fcfcd7);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  top: 190px;
  left: 10px;
}

#right-eye-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e3d234 1%, #fceb51 80%, #fcfcd7);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  top: 210px;
  left: 230px;
```

```html
<div id="head">
  <div id="smile"></div>
  <div id="smile-cover"></div>
  <div id="left-eye"></div>
  <div id="right-eye"></div>
  <div id="left-eye-highlight"></div>
  <div id="right-eye-highlight"></div>
  <div id="left-eye-bottom"></div>
  <div id="right-eye-bottom"></div>
</div>

}
```

Comment: I would be tempted to do this with only one element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change all fixed `px` units to %. First you need to define the base for `width` and `height`, and then you need to find the ratio between any stat and `width` / `height` (`padding-right` / `width` or `padding-top` / `height`). In this case the `width` and `height` are both equal to `500px`, so that's make life easy.

How to calculate:

1. The base value is 500 - `width` & `height` for `#head`. Don't change them for now.
2. Take a fixed value (`100px`), and calculate `100 / 500 * 100` to find the percentage value.
3. Replace the fixed value with the result `20%`.
4. Run the code to see that everything is still in place.
5. Repeat 2-4 all fixed units (except the head's width/height) were replace.
6. Replace the head's `width` & `height` values. I've using `vmin` values, you can control them from JS.

The result:

```css
#head {
  height: 100vmin;
  width: 100vmin;
  /*   border: px solid yellow; */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-70deg, #c9bb34 1%, #fceb51 65%, #fcfcd7);
  left: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1% 1.6% 2%;
}

#smile {
  position: relative;
  height: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 10%, black);
  left: 30%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 10% 70% 20% 30%;
}

#smile-cover {
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  width: 20%;
  height: 34%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fceb51;
  top: 52%;
  left: 20%;
  border-radius: 0 60% 20% 10%;
}

#left-eye {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 10%, black);
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  top: 22%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1% 1.6% 2%;
}

#right-eye {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 1%, black);
  position: absolute;
  width: 26%;
  height: 30%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 48%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0.4% 0.4% 2%;
}

#left-eye-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3.6%;
  height: 4.6%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fceb51, #fcfcd7);
  top: 25%;
  left: 11.6;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 25% 60%;
}

#right-eye-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: 4%;
  height: 6%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fceb51, #fcfcd7);
  top: 25%;
  left: 64%;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 25% 70%;
}

#left-eye-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 14%;
  height: 12%;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-70deg, #fceb51 1%, #fcfcd7);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  top: 38%;
  left: 2%;
}

#right-eye-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24%;
  height: 12%;
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e3d234 1%, #fceb51 80%, #fcfcd7);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  top: 42%;
  left: 46%;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">
  <div id="smile"></div>
  <div id="smile-cover"></div>
  <div id="left-eye"></div>
  <div id="right-eye"></div>
  <div id="left-eye-highlight"></div>
  <div id="right-eye-highlight"></div>
  <div id="left-eye-bottom"></div>
  <div id="right-eye-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use vh, vw or vmax units

example with these different units

```css
/* for test purpose */
#px:checked~#head {
  --unit: 1px;
}

#vh:checked~#head {
  --unit: 0.1vh;
}

#vw:checked~#head {
  --unit: 0.1vw;
}

#vmin:checked~#head {
  --unit: 0.1vmin;
}

#vmax:checked~#head {
  --unit: 0.1vmax;
}
/* var() inside calc() is used for test and update value's unit */
* {transition:0.5s}
#head {
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 500);
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 500);
  /*   border: px solid yellow; */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-70deg, #c9bb34 1%, #fceb51 65%, #fcfcd7);
  left: calc( var(--unit) * 100);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 10px;
}

#smile {
  position: relative;
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 200);
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 200);
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 10%, black);
  left: calc( var(--unit) * 150);
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 250);
  border-radius: 10% 70% 20% 30%;
}

#smile-cover {
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 100);
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 170);
  position: absolute;
  background: #fceb51;
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 260);
  left: calc( var(--unit) *100);
  border-radius: 0 60% 20% 10%;
}

#left-eye {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 10%, black);
  position: absolute;
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 100);
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 100);
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 110);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 5px 8px 10px;
}

#right-eye {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#302e29 1%, black);
  position: absolute;
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 130);
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 150);
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 100);
  left: calc( var(--unit) * 240);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px;
}

#left-eye-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 18);
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 23);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fceb51, #fcfcd7);
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 125);
  left: calc( var(--unit) * 58);
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 25% 60%;
}

#right-eye-highlight {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 20);
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 30);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fceb51, #fcfcd7);
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 125);
  left: calc( var(--unit) * 320);
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 25% 70%;
}

#left-eye-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 70);
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 60);
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-70deg, #fceb51 1%, #fcfcd7);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 190);
  left: calc( var(--unit) * 10);
}

#right-eye-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc( var(--unit) * 120);
  height: calc( var(--unit) * 60);
  /*   border: 1px solid red; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e3d234 1%, #fceb51 80%, #fcfcd7);
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  top: calc( var(--unit) * 210);
  left: calc( var(--unit) * 230);
}
```

```html
<!-- for test purpose -->
Resize smiley from unit :
<input type=radio name="unit" checked id="px">
<label for="px">px</label>
<input type=radio name="unit" id="vh">
<label for="px">vh</label>
<input type=radio name="unit" id="vw">
<label for="px">vw</label>
<input type=radio name="unit" id="vmin">
<label for="px">vmin</label>
<input type=radio name="unit" id="vmax">
<label for="px">vmax</label>
<!-- end test tag -->

<div id="head">
  <div id="smile"></div>
  <div id="smile-cover"></div>
  <div id="left-eye"></div>
  <div id="right-eye"></div>
  <div id="left-eye-highlight"></div>
  <div id="right-eye-highlight"></div>
  <div id="left-eye-bottom"></div>
  <div id="right-eye-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

fork https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvvQYzy

some infos  https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

About demo and css variable https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: There are a lot of cool techniques here that I didn't know about. Thanks for the in-depth response!